# Yotzei for Kerias Shema before bed from Maariv shema?

Tags: shema

Can you be yotzei for the Kerias Shema before bed from the Maariv shema if you daven maariv right before going to bed? Is this bedieved? Should you avoid davening maariv right before bed? Couldn't really find any good source online, thanks!

Comment: Your thoughts are maybe that if you have to read all 3 paras of Shema if you davenned maariv before night, maybe reading all 3 paras in maariv after stars appeared should cover you for Kerias Shema before bed. But I have always thought that the obligation for Kerias Shema before bed is additional to maariv.

Comment: https://www.seforimblog.com/2015/12/evening-prayer-revisited

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok "in addition to" doesn't preclude fulfilling both at the same time.